# Parent child checkbox not working if I remove fieldset and div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code which is working properly for parent/child/subchild relation but I want to remove fieldset and div from my html code and I will add tr and td for each line and then how to modify jquery code for the same.

**html code**

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" class="mainCheckBox" /> Select All <br />
<fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" class="parentCheckBox" /> Parent 1 <br />
    <div class="content">
        <input type="checkbox" value="" name="country"
            class="childCheckBox" /> Child 1<br /> &nbsp; &nbsp;<input
            type="radio" name="cnstates" id="OT" checked />Sub Child 1<br />
        &nbsp; &nbsp;<input type="radio" name="cnstates" id="AT" checked />Sub Child 2
        <br /> <input type="checkbox" value="" name=""country""
            class="childCheckBox" /> Child 2 <br /> &nbsp; &nbsp;<input
            type="radio" name="usstates" id="NY" checked />Sub Child 1<br />
        &nbsp; &nbsp;<input type="radio" name="usstates" id="DC" />Sub Child 2
        DC
    </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" class="parentCheckBox" /> Parent 2 <br />
    <div class="content">
        <input type="checkbox" value="" name="country"
            class="childCheckBox" /> Child 1<br /> &nbsp; &nbsp;<input
            type="radio" name="instates" id="MU" checked />Sub Child 1<br />
        &nbsp; &nbsp;<input type="radio" name="instates" id="DL" checked />Sub Child 2
        <br /> <input type="checkbox" value="" name="country"
            class="childCheckBox" /> Child 2<br /> &nbsp; &nbsp;<input
            type="radio" name="rustates" id="MW" checked />Sub Child 1<br />
        &nbsp; &nbsp;<input type="radio" name="rustates" id="DC" />Sub Child 2
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**Jquery which is working fine with fieldset but how to modify it for tr and td which I will add**

```
$(document).ready(
function() {

$('.mainCheckBox').on('change', function(){
$(this).closest('form').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
});


$('input.childCheckBox').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.parentCheckBox').prop('checked',
        $('input.childCheckBox').length === $('input.childCheckBox:checked').length 
    ); 
});

//clicking the parent checkbox should check or uncheck all child checkboxes
$(".parentCheckBox").click(
    function() {
        $(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find('.childCheckBox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    }
);
//clicking the last unchecked or checked checkbox should check or uncheck the parent checkbox
$('.childCheckBox').click(
    function() {
        if ($(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find('.parentCheckBox').attr('checked') == true && this.checked == false)
            $(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find('.parentCheckBox').attr('checked', false);
        if (this.checked == true) {
            var flag = true;
            $(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find('.childCheckBox').each(
                function() {
                    if (this.checked == false)
                        flag = false;
                }
            );
            $(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find('.parentCheckBox').attr('checked', flag);
        }
    }
);
}
);
```

[jsfiddle.net/YDgHN/43/](http://jsfiddle.net/YDgHN/43/)

**I want to implement parent,child & subchild relation on below code**

```
<form>
    <table width="90%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" class="mainCheckBox" /> Select All
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" class="parentCheckBox" /> Parent 1
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" value="" name="country"
                class="childCheckBox" /> Child 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="radio" name="cnstates" id="OT" checked />Sub
                Child 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="radio" name="cnstates" id="AT" checked />Sub
                Child 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" value="" name="country"
                class="childCheckBox" /> Child 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="radio" name="usstates" id="NY" checked />Sub
                Child 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="radio" name="usstates" id="DC" />Sub Child 2
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" class="parentCheckBox" /> Parent 2
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" value="" name="country"
                class="childCheckBox" /> Child 1
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="radio" name="instates" id="MU" checked />Sub
                Child 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="radio" name="instates" id="DL" checked />Sub
                Child 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" value="" name="country"
                class="childCheckBox" /> Child 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="radio" name="rustates" id="MW" checked />Sub
                Child 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="radio" name="rustates" id="DC" />Sub Child 2</td>
        </tr>

    <tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" class="parentCheckBox" /> Parent 3
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" value="" name="country"
                class="childCheckBox" /> Child 1
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="radio" name="instates" id="MU" checked />Sub
                Child 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="radio" name="instates" id="DL" checked />Sub
                Child 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" value="" name="country"
                class="childCheckBox" /> Child 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="rustates" id="MW" checked />Sub
                Child 1</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="rustates" id="DC" />Sub Child 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        </tr>
    </table>

</form>
```

1) If select all is checked all check box except sub child checbox should be checked

2) if parent is select all child except subchild should be checked

3) if all child are select parent should be select.

Regards,
Pise

Comment: Means what your output will looks like?

Comment: Are you going to change the layout to use tables instead of divs?

Comment: @markpsmith I have changed the code on which I want to implement. please see above last code

Comment: Is this a static layout? It would be much easier if your controls had id values.

Comment: @markpsmith no this is not static its dynamic parent/child/subchild can be of any number. But structure will be like above

Comment: @markpsmith I can add id to each element

Comment: I was thinking that you could create ids for the child elements which would reference the parent checkbox, but I actually don't think that's a great solution.  Unless you're really stuck with using tables, I'd suggest using something that's easier to use with a parent/child structure.  Here's an example using <li> [http://jsfiddle.net/BhaveshKachhadiya/SENV8/100/](http://jsfiddle.net/BhaveshKachhadiya/SENV8/100/)

Comment: @markpsmith I dont want to use fieldset in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your new js.

```
$('.mainCheckBox').on('change', function(){
  $(this).closest('form').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
});


$('input.childCheckBox').change(function() {
  parent = $(this).parent().parent().prevAll("tr:has(.parentCheckBox)").find(".parentCheckBox").last();
  all_checked = true;
  parent.parent().parent().nextUntil("tr:has(.parentCheckBox)").find("[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
    if(!$(this).prop("checked")) all_checked = false;
  });
  parent.prop("checked", all_checked );  

  select_all = true;
  if($(".childCheckBox, .parentCheckBox").not(":checked").length != 0)
    select_all = false;
  $('.mainCheckBox').prop("checked",select_all);  
});

//clicking the parent checkbox should check or uncheck all child checkboxes
$(".parentCheckBox").click(
    function() {        
        $(this).parent().parent().nextUntil("tr:has(.parentCheckBox)").find("[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', this.checked);
    }
);
```

Comment: when I click on parent3 it also check sub child. On parent check only child should be checked and not subchild and same should be with select all, subchild should not be affected on any check uncheck.